# Calculating Difference Once Column turns from False to True

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, difference

I have a Pandas dataframe that is organized like:

```
+-------+-------------------+---------+
| Name  |       Ready       | Apples  |
+-------+-------------------+---------+
| Alice | false             |    1    |
| Bob   | false             |    3    |
| Chris | true              |    10   |
| Alice | true              |    5    |
| Bob   | true              |    7    |
| Dave  | false             |    NaN  |
+-------+-------------------+---------+
```

I want to calculate the difference in Apples that they have once they're ready to be counted - so this would be when the false turns into true. And if they are already ready, I just want the number of apples they have. And if they're never ready, then just NaN. The thing is, there can be multiple False lines per person before it becomes True. For example, we might see that Alice isn't ready 3 times before she finally is ready.

Is there a way to group the names and then figure out when the false --> true to calculate the difference in apples? I want my output table to look something like:

```
+-------+--------------------+
| Name  |    Collected Apples|
+-------+--------------------+
| Alice | 4 (cuz 5-1 = 4)    |
| Bob   | 4                  |
| Chris | 10                 |
| Dave  | NaN                |
+-------+--------------------+
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: group by name, then in each sub-df, shift ready forward, find the row where that changes, extract the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each name has at most one `True` row and one `False` row. We can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) then subtract `True` from `False`:

```
# Pivot to Wide Form
result_df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Ready', values='Apples')
# Calculate Results
result_df = (
        result_df[True] - result_df[False].fillna(0)  # Subtract True from False
).reset_index(name='Collected Apples')
```

`result_df`:

```
    Name  Collected Apples
0  Alice               4.0
1    Bob               4.0
2  Chris              10.0
3   Dave               NaN
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chris', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Dave'],
    'Ready': [False, False, True, True, True, False],
    'Apples': [1.0, 3.0, 10.0, 5.0, 7.0, np.nan]
})
```

Comment: Does this work if there can be multiple True rows?

Comment: No. That was the caveat I put in the first line: "Assuming each name has at most one True row". Corralien's does by negating and summing.

Comment: Wait. What does it mean to have multiple True rows? You want to count values from True to True per person? Like Alice has multiple Falses then a True, Then multiple Falses and a True. And you'd want 2 sums for that?

Comment: It's like consider we check on Alice multiple times to see if she's ready and we just log every time. So whenever she turns "ready" to True, the value of Apples stays the same for her but there can be multiple rows since it gets logged an unknown amount of times - like (Alice - False - 2) --> (Alice - True - 5) --> (Alice - True - 5).

Also, is there a way to group the results with another column? Say that I have another column called "Class" and I want to group on ("Name", "Class")?

Answer (score 1):

Another method in one-line using `np.where`. Change the sign of `False` value:

```
>>> df.assign(Apples=np.where(df['Ready'] == False, -df['Apples'], df['Apples'])) \
      .groupby('Name')['Apples'].sum() \
      .reset_index(name='Collected Apples')

    Name  Collected Apples
0  Alice               4.0
1    Bob               4.0
2  Chris              10.0
3   Dave               0.0
```

Detail of `np.where`:

```
>>> df.assign(Apples=np.where(df['Ready'] == False, -df['Apples'], df['Apples']))

    Name  Ready  Apples
0  Alice  False    -1.0
1    Bob  False    -3.0
2  Chris   True    10.0
3  Alice   True     5.0
4    Bob   True     7.0
5   Dave  False     NaN
```

Comment: Nice! Could use -> `.reset_index(name='Collected Apples')`  instead of separate `rename` and `reset_index` steps.